# How to recover Microsoft Office 2016 after fresh installation option given in windows security in windows 10 home?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2016, recovery, fresh-install

I have a HP laptop.It came with preinstalled Office 2016.This Office 2016 **does not** show in control panel (Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features). This Office is shown in Windows Setting>Apps. I update this preinstalled Office 2016 using Microsoft Store.This Office 2016 does not have a product key.
I am going to use Fresh Start from Windows Security.So like all preinstalled applications, Office 2016 will be lost.So will i have to buy Office 2016 againg after fresh start or will the preinstalled office 2016 can be recovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Office 2016 that is installed and updated via Microsoft Store is called Centennial Version .Before refreshing/reset/clean_install the Windows 10,
1- Note down the account used to download Office 2016 and activate Office 2016.
2- After refreshing the windows 10 ,sign in Microsoft Store using the same account which was used to download/update Office 2016
3- Go to **Updates and Downloads** then **All Owned".
4- Select Office 2016 from the apps list which appear.
5- Click in manage beside Office 2016 in app list then select install for words,power point,excel etc
6- After installation is complete , open Words or any other Office 2016 app
7- It will ask for Microsoft account used to previously activate the office 2016. Enter the account and password then words and also other Office 2016 apps will activated again just by activating one app.

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to reset your computer to factory defaults. First back up your important documents and other things, as resetting destroys all your data on the local C: drive.

You mentioned that you had an HP computer.

1. Turn off your computer.
2. Press the computer power key and the <kbd>F11</kbd> key simultaneously. Hold down the keys until the *Option selection* screen appears.
3. Select *Troubleshoot*.
4. Select *Reset this computer*.
5. There are two options:

   1. "just remove my files" or
   2. "clean the drive completely".

   Select an option. Then click on the reset system. The computer will then return to the factory state and you will need to reset it.

When done all the preinstalled programs including Microsoft Office will return, and the Windows version will be as it was when you purchased it. 
Greetings